# Deleting Lines in a Text File Given Strings From Another File Using Set-String (Powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, security, scripting

Basically what's happening is that I have two files, one with a list of allowed users and another list of users that are actually on the desktop. What I'm trying to do is use a for loop to grab each name in the `AllowedUsers.txt` file, and use Select-String to find any names that match and delete them from the original `Users.txt` (the list of users actually on the desktop). The end goal is to have a list of users that aren't allowed on the desktop left in the `Users.txt` file, where I can then for loop through once again and simply delete those users through command line.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to get this to work as I don't fully grasp how Select-String or for loops work, but any help writing the script would be greatly appreciated.

**Example for `AllowedUsers.txt`** (Input):

```
abbby
Sebastian
Evan
```

**Example for `Users.txt`** (Input):

```
abbby
Evan
Sebastian
Ethan
zachary
```

**Example for edited `Users.txt`** (Desired Output):

```
Ethan
zachary
```

Comment: Hi Jayjayyy. Sorry about the poor formatting of the question. I've added some images of what I'm trying to accomplish. I hope it helps.

Comment: **_please_** post actual text instead of pictures of data. trying to use your demo data would require those who wish to help to _type in themselves what you already have available_.

Comment: Ok. I just posted the plain text of what each file looks like. Also, I'm so sorry for the inconvenience. This is the first time I've ever posted on here.

Comment: Ok I just approved it

Comment: `(Compare-Object (gc .\AllowedUsers.txt) (gc .\Users.txt)|where sideindicator -eq '=>').Inputobject|Set-Content .\Users.txt`

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to do it. unlike the solution by LotPings, it uses the array membership operator `-notin` to see if the items in the general user list are in the allowed list. i did not overwrite the the source user list since that bothers me. [*grin*] you can easily change that, tho.

note that PoSh versions below 3 will need to use `-notcontains` and swap the items to put the collection on the left of the test instead of the right. thanks to `Theo` for the reminder about that!

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$AllowedUsers = @'
abbby
Sebastian
Evan
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

# another fake file read
$AllUsers = @'
abbby
Evan
Sebastian
Ethan
zachary
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

# this presumes the source files are both text and have the same name format
#    the "-notin" operator is NOT case sensitive
$ExcludedUsers = $AllUsers |
    Where-Object {$_ -notin $AllowedUsers}

# send to screen
$ExcludedUsers

# send to text file
$ExcludedUsers |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\BassoftheC_ExcludedUserList.txt"
```

on screen ...

```
Ethan
zachary
```

text file content ...

```
Ethan
zachary
```

Comment: As a sidenote: when you are using PowerShell version below 3.0 you can use the `-notcontains` and reverse the left and right comparison variables like this: `$ExcludedUsers = $AllUsers | Where-Object { $AllowedUsers -notcontains $_ }`

Comment: @Theo - a very good point. do you think i should add that to the answer?

Comment: Sure, be my guest!